# Solution of $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{y}-\sqrt{4x-x^2}$?

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Solution of $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{y}-\sqrt{4x-x^2}$?

I dont know how to get the solution of the equation.Thanks for any hint or detail answer.

Comment: @lanse7pty: Is it written correctly? In its current form, why do you think it has a closed - form solution?

Comment: @Variable I have edit it again. I don't know whether it has a closed-form solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change of function $Y(x)=\frac{1}{y(x)}$ leads to :
$$Y'=-Y^3+\sqrt{4x-x^2}\:Y^2$$
This is an Abell's equation which appears not to be on the solvable kind. Better, use numerical calculus.